# Python using pandas library: How to replace columns and assign them to a datetime_index?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a CSV file with the first three columns representing the given year, month and day. The datatype of these are int64. I want to replace these columns with a datetime index.

Sample from the CSV file:

[image]

I would like to have them merged into one single column with the following format (year-month-day such as: 61-1-1 and have that information stored in one single column with datetime64 datatype

I tried to solve it with this code, though I keep receiving Value errors:

```py
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data[['Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy']])
    
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    
data.drop(['Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I'm wondering what the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

If you rename the columns to year/month/day, [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) will automatically use those. The year should also have 4 digits, so in your case you need to add 1900:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Yr': 61, 'Mo': 1, 'Dy': range(1, 11)})

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data[['Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy']]
                              .assign(Yr=lambda d: d['Yr'].add(1900))
                              .set_axis(['year', 'month', 'day'], axis=1)
                             )
```

Example:

```
   Yr  Mo  Dy       Date
0  61   1   1 1961-01-01
1  61   1   2 1961-01-02
2  61   1   3 1961-01-03
3  61   1   4 1961-01-04
4  61   1   5 1961-01-05
5  61   1   6 1961-01-06
6  61   1   7 1961-01-07
7  61   1   8 1961-01-08
8  61   1   9 1961-01-09
9  61   1  10 1961-01-10
```